# What exactly does org.apache.commons.lang.builder.CompareToBuilder do?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I learned about the `Comparable` interface, for which a class must implement `compareTo` method. A project I am using that method as:

```
public class EmployeeAssignmentTotal implements Comparable<EmployeeAssignmentTotal>, Serializable {

private Employee employee;
private int total;
....
public int compareTo(EmployeeAssignmentTotal other) {
    return new CompareToBuilder()
            .append(employee, other.employee)
            .append(total, other.total)
            .toComparison();
}
```

What exacly does `CompareToBuilder` do here? And how is it interacting with the `employee` and `total` attributes?

---

I did read [the javadocs](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder.html), but I cant make head or tail of what they are doing with the constructor and the multiple `append`s. Does this question indicate unclear intentions and zero research?

Comment: Is the Javadoc (http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder.html) unclear in some way?

Comment: It is unclear in many ways. In particular as how the resulting Integer is calculated or as how the sequence of appends affects the return value.

Comment: I found this highly informative post -- http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/sorting-a-list-by-multiple-attributes-example

Comment: @Shatu your link save my day ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This class is meant to assist you in building `compareTo()`-methods. Imagine you had more than just 2 fields in your class - manually coding your comparison-method could be quite cumbersome.

CompareToBuilder is doing that for you - each `append()` method is adding a new comparison, and all comparisons are `&&`ed.

So the code you posted runs `equals()` on the employee object and `total`.

Answer (score 13):

I was trying to figure out how CompareToBuilder works myself and I came across this post, but I wasn't happy with the answer. For instance, the toComparison method should return a negative integer, a positive integer, or zero as the builder has judged the "left-hand" side as less than, greater than, or equal to the "right-hand" side.

So my question was how the order of appending attributes affect the comparison. To answer that, the only thing I could do was check the source code and I found this:

```
public CompareToBuilder append(int lhs, int rhs) {
    if (this.comparison != 0) {
        return this;
    }
    this.comparison = ((lhs > rhs) ? 1 : (lhs < rhs) ? -1 : 0);
    return this;
}
```

So, basically what is happening is that it will compare the attributes based on the order you append them. In your code example, "employee" will be evaluated first. If the left-hand side attributes evaluates as less than or greater then the right-hand side then, total is disregarded.

The attribute "total" will only be evaluated if "employee" evaluates to equal.